# How to split up levels? (cocos2d,box2d,iphone) to save CPU and memory?

Tags: memory, cocos2d-iphone, cpu, box2d

so I'm going to create large levels. But there's a problem: There's much unseen space (it's a jump'n run like mario bros.) and this will use memory + cpu. so how could I split up my levels? I'm using Box2D+ cocos2d for iphone.

Any ideas?

Mayby just set the `visible` property to `NO`? But it would be still in the memory :(. But what with the box2d bodies? Destroy and recreate them would be to heavy for the FPS, because I have physics built in which should not be recreated. Should I make fix points where i want to split the level up, than if the player is 200 px away it should preload it. and if the player is 200 px away from the last part of the level I unload it. But there would be the problem with the physics, because on the start of the level it has a unique movement and later if i destroy and recreate it it would do the same. but i don't want that.

other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What if you split the level up programmatically into quadrants, like a grid, and ,loaded each square as it got closer to becoming visible in the game.

Comment: yes a goood idea and it would work with box2d...So easy dude thanks!+

Comment: Good, glad to be able to help you out! :)

Comment: How did this work out for you?  Maybe you would consider accepting the answer if it worked out?